How to install bzip2-ruby in mac with ARM?
I am setting up a ruby project and using followings:
ruby:2.7.5
There's an error while installing the bzip2-ruby gem mentioned below:
current directory: /Users/ssingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bzip2-ruby-0.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bzip2.c
In file included from bzip2.c:5:
/Users/ssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-W#warnings]
#warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
 ^
bzip2.c:6:10: fatal error: 'version.h' file not found
#include <version.h>`

I am trying to install it.

The latest version of the bzip2-ruby gem is 14 years old. I am not surprised that it doesn't run with modern versions of Ruby. At that time, Ruby 1.9 was just released. And I am also not surprised that it might have issues installing on a CPU that didn't even exist at that time. Why do you have to use such an old and unmaintained gem? Would using bzip2-ffi instead be an option? That gem seems to be still active.

Previously, we were using ubuntu for our project and now we are trying to setup on Mac with M1 chip.
I also think we may need to change our gem to some alternative gem which is maintained.
Thanks @spickermann

Ruby 2.7 isn't maintained and supported anymore. You should upgrade to a newer version of Ruby anyway.
